# Looking for a good resource to learn to use CUDA with C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, cuda

I want to start using CUDA. My programming environment is VS 2010, C#.Net 4.0. Already downloaded CUDA SDK and Latest Drivers. I spend few hours looking for resources to learn how to make the connection; but there are lots of options and little information about each one of them: GPU.NET, Cloo, OpenTK, Cudafy, etc. and couldn't figure out which one is more reliable or popular.

Eventually I'll be using this in a commercial project, so I try to stay away from opensource projects that die after a while and there is not good support and reliability assurance around them.

I would appreciate it if someone could provide some information about which tool is more mature and reliable, and direct me to some resources.

Comment: Your title says you want suggestions for how to learn how to do CUDA programming with C#, but your closing statement says you want opinions about which libraries are better. Asking for opinions leads down the subjective there-is-no-right-answer path...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cudafy seems to cover the bases fairly well.  I'm not familiar with the other projects you mentioned.  I too initially wanted to start CUDA development from the comfort of C#, but eventually gave that up to work with CUDA in C++, using the NVidia CUDA toolkit.

You have enough new concepts to get your head around learning core CUDA itself. Adding a third party layer on top of that only adds to the conceptual load. I'd suggest learning CUDA on its own terms first (in C++), then once you are proficient in core CUDA you can take a look at .NET layers and evaluate how well each exposes core CUDA for the application you have in mind.